# How can I use Humor Sans in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ubuntu-18.04

I want to create an XKCD-style graph of a ROC curve with matploblib. It mostly works fine, but I don't understand why it doesn't use humor sans. It is definitely installed on my system:

```
$ fc-list | grep -i humor
/home/user/.local/share/fonts/Humor-Sans.ttf: Humor Sans:style=Regular
```

How can I make matplotlib use the Humor-Sans font?

I already tried adding `fontname='Humor Sans'`:

```
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1328:
UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['Humor Sans'] not found.
Falling back to DejaVu Sans
```

### My Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

with plt.xkcd():
    xs = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
    plt.plot(xs, (1 / (-xs) + 50) / 50)
    plt.plot(xs, xs)
    plt.title('ROC Curve')
    plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
    plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
    plt.savefig('xkcd-roc-explanation.png')
```

### Current result

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matplotlib aparently has it's own cache file. On my system, I could solve this issue by executing

```
mv ~/.cache/matplotlib/fontList.json ~/.cache/matplotlib/fontList-backup.json
```

Comment: Removing the font list cache essentially forces a rebuild of the font cache. I don't think the answer that I posted is any more "proper" since it uses the private `_rebuild` method, but there ya go.

Answer (score 6):

You can force a rebuild of the font cache via:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager
matplotlib.font_manager._rebuild()
```

then check the font availability

```
matplotlib.font_manager.findfont('Humor Sans')
```

Comment: After following these instructions, I had to restart my ipython shell for matplotlib to find the font.